What is the science on preteen kids playing moderate (less than 9 h /wk) video games?
What are long term effects of preteen kids playing moderate video games? Or is it the same as any screen time?
The axes I'm most interested in are

competitive vs cooperative,
screen time vs video game time (passive vs active),
playing together in-person vs playing alone (regardless of online multiplayer)

I'm clicking through search results on pubmed but I'm not so good at this. I am only interested in projected long term psychosocial effects.
The backstory is that I have a couple kids who are currently not playing games much. I have started playing games with them for cuddle time because when I start to play they come and cuddle with me which is, frankly, good for my mental health. So it's daddy time. Social, not a babysitter, and nonviolent. But it is addictive. They ask me to play the next day, or again the same evening. Honestly I've taken it as an opportunity to teach moderation, and emphasize that we have to be able to stop quickly for any reason. Like a conversation, homework, bedtime, etc. I have repeated (and modeled) this lesson many times. But now my partner is concerned because she sees the signs of addiction too. So what do longitudinal studies on video games say?
There is no chance we aren't going to moderate the time, and while I plan to allow occasional solo play (eg 3D mental rotation is something my daughter can benefit from practicing and I have a couple puzzle games that are good for that), mainly I want to use games to get cuddles while I still can.
One significant factor is that my younger son is autistic and we are therefore appropriately concerned about his long term social development, which is a challenge currently.

I'm not sure if the science you're looking for exists, but as a general rule you want to make sure that socializing and in person interaction is still happening in your kids lives. When I was growing up in the 90s video games usually meant that there were at least two of you together in a social situation. Now that's not always true. I don't think you're going to find a hard and fast rule, but what you want to avoid is your kids never socializing, and sitting by themselves playing games all the time.

@Cdn_Dev, I think this is a good answer. Would you please write that and submit it as an answer?

The harmful effects of videogames/addiction are predominantly due to an absence of the things you'd otherwise be doing.
Video games are a red herring here. If teens were equally eagerly doing another activity to the same degree, thereby depriving themselves of other life activities, you'd see the same harmful effects. Addiction is addiction, and trying to tailor your parenting solely to video games and nothing else is not going to be the more productive route here.

playing together in-person vs playing alone (regardless of online multiplayer)

Also, especially because of your autistic son, I would suggest you don't dismiss online multiplayer as a third individual option with its own merits here.
Online multiplayer can provide social experiences with the safeguard of being relatively anonymous and able to shut it out at a moment's notice, which might be a very beneficial middle ground for an autistic person who struggles with socialization.
Anonimity cuts both ways though. People online can act in a way that doesn't have to reflect on their personal life. This can lead to intentionally crude behavior, but it can similarly provide your son the ability to experiment with social personas without needing to feel personally committed to them.
I don't know your son, I can't judge if that is a particular struggle for him; but if he struggles with socialization or social anxiety, I'd recommend you explore this avenue as a viable socialization exercise.
Personal note: this is precisely how I learned to manage my social anxiety as a teenager. I migrated from talking to strangers via video games, to talking to real people in my area, to talking to real life classmates via MSN Messenger and the likes, and ended up finding enough confidence to be social in real life.

"mainly I want to use games to get cuddles while I still can."

Be very aware of misincentivization. I'm not saying this is happening right now, but if this is your goal, you are at risk of provoking gaming as an activity not because the child wants to play said video game, but because it wants to please you, or because you subconsciously egg them on.
Doing things without wanting to do them leads to dogmatic behavior which can eventually turn into irrational compulsion if left unchecked.

[your response to the above] you cast any/every social hobby as misincentivization, and that is laughable, but I'll take your warning and look for any sign my kid doesn't want to play video games 

The specific activity is irrelevant for what I'm trying to address. It's the potential pressure coming from an external source and authority figure (you) for an ulterior more (getting cuddles) that can lead to the activity (any activity) being done for a reason other than wanting to engage in the activity itself.
This can be wielded for good (e.g. getting kids to do chores for an ulterior benefit even if they don't like doing chores), but it can also be misapplied and end up creating unhelpful behavioral patterns.
I'm not saying that's what happening here or that that's what definitely will happen; but I am cautioning you ahead of time before it might get to that stage.

Honestly, there's a lot to explore in your question (and it is valuable to answer these things).
I suggest breaking this up into more targeted questions if you want to actually address all of those points. E.g. harm from screen time, benefits of games as mental development tools, avoiding addiction and teaching self-moderation, potentially using videogames as an entry point to socialization for someone who struggles to otherwise socialize, learning as a parent to cope with less physical affection from your children, ...
These are all different goals with different considerations.

FYI - From a respected psychology journal this month (Dec. 2024):
Title
Learning and Transfer: A Perspective From Action Video Game Play
Abstract
A growing body of research documents the positive impact that action video game play has on a range of cognitive skills. Such a result, in which training on one task promotes a broad variety of benefits, is a rarity in the cognitive training domain. Instead, the more typical result is that training on one task promotes benefits on that task alone with only limited transfer to untrained tasks. We have proposed that action video game play promotes broad generalization by first enhancing attentional control abilities. This in turn allows for more information to be accrued as one experiences a new task and thus faster learning of that new task. Possible theoretical and practical considerations of such a view are discussed.
Source: https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/09637214241287171
Authors: Daphne Bavelier and C. Shawn Green
Journal: Current Directions in Psychological Science

P.S. I’ve heard that the Israeli army staffs its electronic warfare controls with gamers.

This isn't a science site per se, so I'll add my story:
I'm not calling myself autistic, but I can relate with some of the signs of it.
I wasn't very good with people. Not terrible, but I was pretty low on the bottom half of the social ladder. I did not really like going outside and entertaining myself wasn't my strong suit.
I got my PC at age 13 and I've spent many hours in front of it. That might seem bad, but I actually had a lot of people I could talk to! Via MSN, or chat groups, via games, or some forums. I was pretty active there.
I had time to think before writing, and I could rephrase the sentence before (or after) submitting. I actually learned a lot of social skills, choosing my wording so I could lay out my intent without people responding unexpectedly (at least to me). There is less pressure to instantly respond, if you respond 30 sec or 15 mins later, it isn't an issue.
While writing this, I remembered some of the people I've chatted with and I'm thinking back to that time in a positive way. I even went so far as to travel to a girl I met (which was possible then, heheh). That didn't go as expected, and that was a mighty fine adventure.
And now, 25 years down the road, I have a good IT job as programmer. I didn't speak 'person', per se, but speaking 'code/computer' has resulted a solid career, a good house and enjoyment in life.
TL;DR: The point that I'm trying to make is not that gaming and spending more time at a screen is something to be actively promoted. I'm saying that it isn't a bad thing either :). I have a somewhat unique way of thinking which I see as a good thing, not a limitation.
The only thing that might've improved it, would have been doing more on the computer WITH my parents. Perhaps a game, or another form of challenge/puzzle. Or maybe a form of interest in the forums I visited.

thanks for providing my first answer in the form of a personal anecdote. I do think the implications of your story wrap up the best answer that I can formulate based on what I have heard from you and others here and elsewhere through my research over the last week. I appreciate your point that this is not a scientific community and I would add that parenting is not (and should never be) a science. Considering I definitely want to engage with my kid around games and computers, I can't find any evidence-based implication that doing so in moderation could be anything but positive.
